# Generic variable number of parameter passing in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a method findByProperties(Parameter... p); so it can take any number of parameters. But what I am confused is if I had to call this method and I do not know the number of parameters how do I do that

suppose I have a list with parameters, and the size of the list changes each time you call the method, the how would I add the parameters from the list to the method call?

```
for(ArrayList<Parameter> p : list){
   findByProperties(p);  //not sure what to do here
 }
```

EDIT:

this was the solution:

```
Parameter[] paramArray = new ArrayList<Parameter>().toArray(new Parameter[]{});
findByProperties(paramArray);
```

Comment: Why don't you have a method that takes a `List<Parameter>` as parameter?

Comment: I need to use generics in my method!

Comment: @Benz_java you can 'stack' generics like that (although it's on the cost of readability): `List<Parameter<String>>`

Comment: "I cannot convert the list to array and pass it as well!" What did you try? Did you search for "convert list to array"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Parameter[] paramArray = new ArrayList<Parameter>().toArray(new Parameter[]{});
findByProperties(paramArray);
```

It's the same as something like:

```
findProperties(param1, param2);
```

Because Java internally transforms a varargs-list into an array, so you can pass an array, too.

Comment: @Benz_java you can always _accept_ an answer of a question you asked yourself. (--> +15 for the answer, +2 for the acceptor)

Answer (score 3):

You can override `findByProperties` to take either varargs or a `List<Parameter>`. One can then relay to the other:

```
void findByProperties(Parameter... p) {
    findByProperties(Arrays.asList(p));
}

void findByProperties(List<Parameter> p) {
    . . .
}
```

Then you can call `findByProperties` with either a variable argument list of `Parameter` objects, or with a `List<Parameter>` argument. Using `Arrays.asList` does not create a new array; it just wraps the existing array in a `List` implementation; thus, this is less work than creating a new `Parameter[]` array from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Methods can declare a parameter that accepts from zero to many arguments, a so-called var-arg method.

A var-arg parameter is decalared with the sintax type... name; for instance:

doSomething(int... x){}

Comment: This is not the question; OP already has a var-args method. The question is, how to use it when starting with an `ArrayList<Parameter>` in the calling code.

Comment: Sorry, I try to clarify: the var-arg method above  "findByProperties(Parameter... p)" accepts zero-to-many Parameter BUT in the example he pass another type, an ArrayList. So in order to pass the correct parameters he has to retrieve the various Parameter from each ArrayList and pass them to the findByProperties method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can also pass in an array for a method with a variable argument. So you can use the `toArray` method of the parameter list to convert the `List<Parameter>` to a `Parameter[]`, which can be passed directly to `findByProperties`:

```
for (ArrayList<Parameter> p : list){
    Parameter[] param = p.toArray(new Parameter[p.size()])
    findByProperties(param);
}
```

If you need to do this other places too, you could also make a convenience method:

```
public ... findByProperties(List<Parameter> p) {
    return findByProperties(p.toArray(new Parameter[p.size()]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

findByProperties(Parameter... p);

u can invoke the method findByProperties();  (or)   findByProperties(p);

but not findByProperties(p,p,p);

Comment: This is simply wrong. With an argument declaration of `Parameter... p`, you can invoke the method with _any number of arguments_ of type `Parameter`.